# mongo db - schema for implementing like feature in webapp

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

i have a mongodb database, in which i got 2 collections. `posts` and `users`.

posts json structure is like

```
{title:"Title", content:"content goes here", postedby: "userid"}
```

and users is like

```
{username:"", name:""}
```

Now i need to implement a like feature, where users like the posts.

**Solution 1**

i can put an inner array in users like

```
{username:"", name:"", likes:[postid1,postid2..]}
```

issue here is its easy to query posts which a user liked. But difficult to get people who liked an article.

**Solution 2**

i can put an inner array in posts like

```
{title:"Title", content:"content goes here", postedby: "userid", like:[userid1,userid2 ..]}
```

issue here is its easy to get people who liked an article. But difficult to query posts which a user liked.

How can i tackle this?
currently i am thinking about having both the ways. Just like keeping inner arrays in both collections. I know i am keeping redundant data, is it the best way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 11):

I personally would not go for a like array here.

It is all too common that likes grow out of control with a person liking way too many posts; to the point where this could hinder the amount of top level user data you could store in that document.

You have also got to consider your querying pattern here. You will most likely want to do some sort of graphed aggregation of likes across multiple users. Currently to do such a thing dynamically you must use the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ (pre-aggregative reports: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/ would also be a useful tool here but I will skip that) using `$unwind`.

`$unwind` is a in-memory operation which can be slow on distanced aggregation of many users especially if each user sits on at least 1000 likes (50x1000 is already pushing the in-memory limit for `$unwind` and a post `$group` `$sort`, which has a memory limit of 10% of the systems memory). All in all the aggregation framework will not a peformant method to query for these likes.

MongoDB can easily store this structure though, evne in its gorwing form since the subdocument is like maybe 12 bytes for each entry so you can just use power of 2 sizes ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes ) allocation to remedy the problems you would normally get (fragmentation) with using the structure.

So considering this I would keep likes in a separate collection. It is true that you will lose the single round trip notation of housing the likes in the user document but I believe that what I stated above is worth the price.

Comment: Can you tell me the schema i should have in case of separate like collection ...?

Comment: @ravisuhag Since a user can have a massive number of likes I would probably put those likes themselves into a separate collection of the form `{_id:(), user_id: (), media_id: (), collection: (), date_liked: ()}` the collection field will alow you to like multiple media items, i.e. wall posts and videos.

Answer (score 5):

The important question to ask yourself is what are the different ways you will need to fetch this data?

You *can* query users for who liked a particular page with `user.find({"likes":postId})` in the first case and the opposite query of that in the second case.   But is that a good idea?  You want to avoid continuously growing documents in MongoDB plus you probably won't want to know for a particular user *all* the pages they like, and for a particular page *all* the users that like it.

So how about saving likes in their own collection and only keeping aggregates (i.e. counts) in user and pages collections?  You also have an option to keep the most recent "N" likes in page or whatever else is most useful to your application and its performance.

It's seldom possible to design "ideal" schema in MongoDB without knowing the use case (i.e. read and write patterns) and what the requirements around it is.

Answer (score 4):

I think just keeping the liked array in the post document will be good enough.

You can get the posts which are liked by user using the like field. The performance would be also good if you have index on like field.

The only disadvantage is that with this approach the size of post object is varying according to the length of like array. Mongo is not very good at handling these kind of data structures, so if you will have thousands of likes for a post keeping all of the ids might decrease the performance in querying but in general posts don't have that many likes and in overall your system would work fine I believe. You may think of having a limit on the number of liked ids for a post (keep the last 1000 user id for example) to ensure that the size of a document won't grow extraordinarily.